# how to set condition in objective function in cvxpy

Tags: cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I have a brute force optimization algorithm with the objective function of the form:
`np.clip(x @ M, a_min=0, a_max=1) @ P`
where x is a Boolean decision vector, M is a Boolean matrix/tensor and P is a probability vector. As you can guess, x @ M as an inner product can have values higher than 1 where is not allowed as the obj value should be a probability scalar or vector (if M is a tensor) between 0 to 1. So, I have used numpy.clip to fix the x @ M to 0 and 1 values. How can I set up a mechanism like clip in cvxpy to achieve the same result? I have spent ours on internet with no lock so I appreciate any hint. I have been trying to use this to replicate clip but it raises `Exception: Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint or chain constraints, e.g., 1 >= x >= 0.` As a side note, since cvxpy cannot handle tensors, I loop through tensor slices with `M[s]`.

```
n = M.shape[0]
m = M.shape[1]
w = M.shape[2]
max_budget_of_decision_variable = 7
x = cp.Variable(n, boolean=True)

obj = 0
for s in range(m):
    for w in range(w):
        if (x @ M[s])[w] >= 1:
            (x @ M[s])[w] = 1
    obj += x @ M[s] @ P

objective = cp.Maximize(obj)
cst = []
cst += [cp.sum(y) <= max_budget_of_decision_variable ]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints = cst)
```

As an example, consider `M = np.array([ [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]])` and `P = np.array([0.05, 0.15, 0.1, 0.15, 0.5, 0.05])`.

Comment: It looks like ``cp.Maximize(cp.sum(cp.minimum(x@M,1))@P)`` or some variant of that taking into account the dimensions. I will not try to go into the details because the code you attach is not reproducible so it is hard to figure out the shapes and also does not correspond fully to the description because you only take care of the upper bound 1 but ignore 0 (which I also do in my suggestion). Try with some simpler shapes first to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Michal. It solved my issue like a charm. You were a Godsent man!